# Dual boot W8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04 on SSD/HDD

Tags: dual-boot, hard-drive, ssd

I recently bought a new laptop which has an 8 GB ssd and a 1 TB HDD, pre-installed with W8.1. I'm used to creating a partition on a HDD to install Ubuntu on. However, with the new SSD I'm not sure as to how I must go about installing Ubuntu in this case. The make of my laptop is a Lenovo Y50-70... I'd appreciate some quick advice on how I should go about creating a dual boot, as I need Ubuntu for work and windows for media/gaming/word/etc...

Comment: It's done in the same way as if you were using a HDD. There isn't any real difference but the storage technology.

Comment: Wait, so I still basically just free up space on the hdd, and install ubuntu on it? Do I have to change to Legacy from UEFI and any other technical details?

Comment: No, just everything you would do to the HDD, you now do to the SSD. And btw. you don't have to disable UEFI. Ubuntu works pretty well with UEFI by now.